# read.csv.sql reads only column name

Tags: r

I have been trying to read a very big (compared to computer's memory) data set and I thought it would be easier to use sqldf to import only selected columns.
However, my code only imports the file's columns names and none of the data.

```
library(sqldf)

ka <- read.csv.sql("Filename.csv",header=TRUE,sep="\t",
                                  sql="SELECT Business,Product FROM file")
```

ka then gives me Business, Product column names, but not the data below them.
I also get the message `<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)`

What is more weird, is that the above function works with a sample on my personal laptop, but not with the employer's data.

Would anyone know what could be the reason?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Are you sure sep="\t" is required? I tried it with some sample csv data I made, and it worked ok without that

Comment: For reading big files, maybe try: `data.table::fread("filename.csv", nrow = 10, select = c("Business", "Product"))`

Comment: Are the field separators and the end-of-line characters the same on the two files?  Are the operating systems the same?